# Pseudo random number not matching book in Java

Tags: java, random-seed

I am new to Java and am currently learning about random numbers. In my book it has a challenge activity to generate a random number between 100 - 149. Then it will automatically output 2 numbers and see if your code matches what they outputted. The code seems to work just fine, but my numbers are not matching. I was wondering what I could be doing wrong in my code?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomGenerateNumbers {
public static void main (String [] args) {
  Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
  Random randGen = new Random();
  int seedVal;

  seedVal = scnr.nextInt();
  randGen.setSeed(seedVal);

  seedVal = randGen.nextInt(50) + 100;
  System.out.println(seedVal);

  seedVal = randGen.nextInt(50) + 100;
  System.out.println(seedVal);


   }
}
```

The issue is that the code is producing what I would expect, it just does not match what the book is getting.

The book is using the value 102 and it is producing 113 and 124. My outputs are coming back as 112 and 102

Comment: What version of Java is your book expecting?  What version of Java are you running?

Comment: Its kinda weird. It is actually an eBook called ZyBooks. I actually program from the website. So I have no idea what version is running.

Comment: On [Java 8u112](https://ideone.com/4klppS), it produces the book values.

Comment: Ok thanks! That is actually really handy. I'm still super confused though because I was comparing the code to that website and it was the exact same code. I even copied and pasted it and I'm still receiving the exact same answers! Thanks anyways though!

Comment: Can you do a `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));`?

Comment: So, I talked to my teacher and he said that I have the right answer. For some reason it just isn't working on my account. So we are all good haha. Thanks for all of the help!!